Why does a random term in a large GAMM model make the curves spiky and wiggly?
I am creating several GAMM models with similar structures to dynamically model an acoustic parameter across realizations from multiple subjects, who are included as random smooths in my models.
In the largest datasets, the curves become wiggly when the random terms are included: what could explain this? I can add that I’ve tested several adjustments (modifying the number of knots, the gamma value, the n.grid parameter in the plots) without significant impact on curve smoothness. How can I interpret this, and what could I improve or further check in my data to avoid this effect?
Here is the maximal autocorrelated model with all predictors included (whether or not third-level terms are included does not affect the described effect)
g.PKF.VCV.dur.AR.min.period.shape <- bam(F2F1 ~ V1.ord + V2.ord + stress.ord +
                                #level 1 smooth terms
                                   s(time.i, bs="cr", k=4) +
                                   #s(period_num, bs="cr", k=4) +
                                   s(logdurz, bs="cr", k=4) +
                                #level 2 by terms
                                   s(time.i, by=stress.ord, k=4) +
                                   s(time.i, by=V1.ord, k=4) +
                                   s(time.i, by=V2.ord, k=4) +
                                   s(period_num, by=V1.ord, k=4) +
                                   s(period_num, by=V2.ord, k=4) +
                                   s(period_num, by=stress, k=4) +
                                #level 2: 2d smooth
                                   ti(time.i, logdurz, k=c(4,4)) +
                                   ti(time.i, period_num, k=c(4,4)) +
                                #level 3: 2d smooth by terms
                                   ti(time.i, period_num, k=c(4,4), by=stress.ord) +
                                   ti(time.i, period_num, k=c(4,4), by=V1.ord) +
                                   ti(time.i, period_num, k=c(4,4), by=V2.ord) +
                                #random terms
                                   s(time.i, speaker, bs="fs", m=1, k=4) +
                                   s(mot, bs="re"), 
                                 data = df.w.VCV.long,
                                 method = "fREML",
                                 nthreads=12,
                                 rho=r1, AR.start = df.w.VCV.long$start.event)
saveRDS(g.PKF.VCV.dur.AR.min.period.shape, "g.PKF.VCV.dur.AR.min.period.shape")

period_effect <- plot_smooth(g.PKF.CV.dur.AR, view = "time.i", plot_all = "period_num", rm.ranef = FALSE, n.grid = 100, return.plot = TRUE, rug=F)$fv


Here is an example structure of one of my dfs:
glimpse(df.long)
Rows: 37,689
Columns: 37
$ word            <fct> ciepło, człowieczej, człowiek, człowiek, człowiek, człowiek, płaczu, słońce, właściwie, właśnie, wykłada…
$ C              <chr> "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w",…
$ V2             <fct> ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, a, ɔ, a, a, a, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, a, ɔ, a, a, a, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, a, ɔ, a, a, a,…
$ speaker        <fct> JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP...
$ stress         <fct> unstressed, unstressed, stressed, stressed, stressed, stressed, stressed, stressed, unstressed, stressed…
$ F2F1             <dbl> 2018, 1883, 1870, 2082, 1982, 1866, 2109, 1933, 1839, 1891, 1923, 1683, 2011, 1929, 1872, 2008, 2013, 19…
$ time.i         <dbl> 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.5625, …
$ logdurz        <dbl[,1]> <matrix[43 x 1]>
$ period         <fct> 1921-1940, 1921-1940, 1921-1940, 1921-1940, 1921-1940, 1921-1940, 1921-1940, 1921-1940, 1921-1940, 1…
$ period_num     <dbl> 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 19…
$ start.event    <lgl> TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALS…
$ C1bis.ord      <ord> labials, dentals, dentals, dentals, dentals, dentals, labials, dentals, labials, labials, velars, dental…
$ V2.ord         <ord> ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, a, ɔ, a, a, a, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, a, ɔ, a, a, a, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, a, ɔ, a, a, a,…
$ stress.ord     <ord> unstressed, unstressed, stressed, stressed, stressed, stressed, stressed, stressed, unstressed, stressed…
$ V2.stress.ord  <ord> ɔ_unstressed, ɔ_unstressed, ɔ_stressed, ɔ_stressed, ɔ_stressed, ɔ_stressed, a_stressed, ɔ_stressed, a_un…

I am adding the model results here, with one of the two random terms
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
F2F1 ~ V2.ord + C1bis.ord + stress.ord + s(time.i, bs = "cr", 
    k = 4) + s(period_num, bs = "cr", k = 4) + s(logdurz, bs = "cr", 
    k = 4) + s(time.i, by = stress.ord, k = 4) + s(time.i, by = V2.ord, 
    k = 4) + s(time.i, by = C1bis.ord, k = 4) + s(period_num, 
    by = C1bis.ord, k = 4) + s(period_num, by = V2.ord, k = 4) + 
    s(period_num, by = stress, k = 4) + ti(time.i, logdurz, k = c(4, 
    4)) + ti(time.i, period_num, k = c(4, 4)) + ti(time.i, period_num, 
    k = c(4, 4), by = stress.ord) + ti(time.i, period_num, k = c(4, 
    4), by = V2.ord) + ti(time.i, period_num, k = c(4, 4), by = C1bis.ord) + 
    s(time.i, speaker, bs = "fs", m = 1, k = 4)

Parametric coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           800.7019     9.4121   85.07   <2e-16 ***
V2.ordu              -155.0325     1.6736  -92.63   <2e-16 ***
V2.ordɛ               -61.2842     2.2565  -27.16   <2e-16 ***
V2.orda              -189.1734     1.4311 -132.18   <2e-16 ***
V2.ordɔ              -206.4682     1.4116 -146.27   <2e-16 ***
C1bis.orddentals      161.1823     0.9999  161.20   <2e-16 ***
C1bis.ordalveolars    156.2315     1.9152   81.57   <2e-16 ***
C1bis.ordvelars        27.2871     1.0565   25.83   <2e-16 ***
stress.ordunstressed    8.1963     0.7978   10.27   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                              edf Ref.df        F  p-value    
s(time.i)                                   2.998  3.000 1181.357  < 2e-16 ***
s(period_num)                               1.889  1.982   17.044  < 2e-16 ***
s(logdurz)                                  2.898  2.991  320.547  < 2e-16 ***
s(time.i):stress.ordunstressed              2.916  2.994   13.223  < 2e-16 ***
s(time.i):V2.ordu                           2.999  3.000  940.385  < 2e-16 ***
s(time.i):V2.ordɛ                           2.959  2.999  104.662  < 2e-16 ***
s(time.i):V2.orda                           2.999  3.000 1393.420  < 2e-16 ***
s(time.i):V2.ordɔ                           2.999  3.000 1648.835  < 2e-16 ***
s(time.i):C1bis.orddentals                  3.000  3.000 3022.440  < 2e-16 ***
s(time.i):C1bis.ordalveolars                2.999  3.000  837.517  < 2e-16 ***
s(time.i):C1bis.ordvelars                   2.992  3.000  259.132  < 2e-16 ***
s(period_num):C1bis.orddentals              2.957  2.995  876.893  < 2e-16 ***
s(period_num):C1bis.ordalveolars            2.863  2.981   55.386  < 2e-16 ***
s(period_num):C1bis.ordvelars               2.690  2.915   94.769  < 2e-16 ***
s(period_num):V2.ordu                       2.962  2.997   96.206  < 2e-16 ***
s(period_num):V2.ordɛ                       2.952  2.997   25.203  < 2e-16 ***
s(period_num):V2.orda                       2.972  2.997   44.416  < 2e-16 ***
s(period_num):V2.ordɔ                       2.982  2.998   61.999  < 2e-16 ***
s(period_num):stressstressed                2.815  2.967   12.539 8.55e-07 ***
s(period_num):stressunstressed              1.004  1.004    7.874  0.00486 ** 
ti(time.i,logdurz)                          8.678  8.966  497.046  < 2e-16 ***
ti(time.i,period_num)                       8.208  8.749   11.411  < 2e-16 ***
ti(time.i,period_num):stress.ordunstressed  4.648  5.706    3.567  0.00180 ** 
ti(time.i,period_num):V2.ordu               5.477  6.694    5.193 1.64e-05 ***
ti(time.i,period_num):V2.ordɛ               7.688  8.575    4.412 1.48e-05 ***
ti(time.i,period_num):V2.orda               7.492  8.374   11.048  < 2e-16 ***
ti(time.i,period_num):V2.ordɔ               2.855  2.975   15.638  < 2e-16 ***
ti(time.i,period_num):C1bis.orddentals      8.460  8.861   46.585  < 2e-16 ***
ti(time.i,period_num):C1bis.ordalveolars    2.153  2.507    5.411  0.00532 ** 
ti(time.i,period_num):C1bis.ordvelars       7.289  8.169   30.590  < 2e-16 ***
s(time.i,speaker)                          86.448 87.000   92.065  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Rank: 246/247
R-sq.(adj) =  0.405   Deviance explained = 40.6%
fREML = 1.9385e+06  Scale est. = 40879     n = 288031


Welcome to Cross Validated ! There could be several reasons for this apparent instability. On the face of it, it could be over-fitting the random structure and/or the estimated variance of the random effects could be very large or various other issues. My money is on overfitting. Please can you edit the question and provide the output of summary(model)

If this term s(time.i,speaker) is treated as a random effect (then why are you plotting it by sticking with rm.ranef = FALSE, then it could well be causing add behaviour as you have m=1 which can make the smooths piece-wise linear (though that wouldn't account for the bumps you show above). Did you plot the estimated smooths themselves (plot.gam) to see which are bumpy and hence which might be causing those bumps? There's a lot of factor by terms in the model; how is plot_smooth() determining which factor(s) to condition on when predicting over time.i?
